# How to set up a different database for testing in prisma?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, prisma, express-graphql, prisma-graphql

I want to use a different database for testing my app instead of local database.

this is my env file

```
# Environment
NODE_ENV=development

# Backend
API_PORT=4000
APP_SECRET=omg
DASHBOARD_URL=http://localhost:1234

# Prisma
PRISMA_ENDPOINT=http://localhost:4466
PRISMA_SECRET=omg
PRISMA_MANAGEMENT_API_SECRET=omg
```

what I have tried is changing the Prisma endpoint into `http://localhost:4466/default/test`

but, then how to dynamically change the endpoint? so that when I need to run the app it will point to that `http://localhost:4466/default/default` and when I need to run test suits it will point to that `http://localhost:4466/default/test` endpoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can testing against a test stage.

all you need is two different env file. one is for the development environment and one is for testing environment.

- on .env.dev: `http://localhost:4466/default/default`
- on .env.test: `http://localhost:4466/default/test`

after that, you can run docker separately for development and test environment.